# Unable to read socket response C server to Java client

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

I've searched everywhere including here for possible solutions and tried some of the answers I found with no success.

I implemented a simple Java tcp socket client. The client works really well with one Java server but I keep having problems receiving the response from a server coded in C.
The server appears to be handling the transaction correctly and it sends a reply accordingly. The problem lies in the client being able to receive the incoming stream of the reply.
This was my initial implementation:

```
        String msg_out = message;
        String reply;

        //the stream object to transmit message to server
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        outStream.writeBytes(msg_out + '\n');
        outStream.flush();

        //try to break away from locked read 
        //clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);

        //initial implementation
        //the object to receive reply server
        BufferedReader replyStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        reply = replyStream.readLine();

        System.out.println("Reply from "+ host + ":" + port + " -> " + reply);
```

I downloaded Wireshark and used it to monitor the tcp packet traffic between the client and server in the corresponding port the server socket is listening on. I saw multiple suggestions in other threads with similar topics, I unfortunately was not able to get any of those solutions to work for me. I found that the packet containing the reply has the flag value set to PSH (for do not buffer steam upon receiving, process immediately). I thought that the Java client by attempting to buffer the reply was causing the connection to reset (RST that appears in the failure packet, which is the next one that occurs) because of this flag. I tried testing with this implementation I found in a thread here trying to read the reply byte by byte but to no avail:

```
  try {
            DataInputStream in = new  DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];
            boolean end = false;
            String messageString = "";
            messageByte[0] = in.readByte();
            messageByte[1] = in.readByte();
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messageByte, 0, 2);

            int bytesToRead = byteBuffer.getShort();
            System.out.println("About to read " + bytesToRead + " octets");

            //The following code shows in detail how to read from a TCP socket

            while(!end)
            {
                bytesRead = in.read(messageByte);
                messageString += new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
                if (messageString.length() == bytesToRead )
                {
                    end = true;
                }
            }


            System.out.println("Server Reply: " + messageString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I do not have access to the source code for the C server but its developer swears to me that the problem is not on his end and I believe him. I also know he can’t make changes to it as it works with every other client architecture in use, the one I’m coding happens to be the only Java client one that interacts with this C based server. Is there an error in my implementation or is there another implementation I could use to read the reply stream in a more fool-proof way?

Here's the results of trying to run the client/server comm process:

```
[2/10/17 14:23:49:658 EST] 00000031 SystemOut     O Outgoing transaction message:C00052!GDT43000KU!01!D-10!G-11!NORMAL!|                   
[2/10/17 14:23:49:658 EST] 0000011e SystemOut     O Buffersize in stream:8192
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemOut     O About to read 12336 octets
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:67)
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:118)
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R     at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:94)
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R     at com.gf.btv.RTDLTSS.domain.LTSSClient.TCPClientRequest(LTSSClient.java:141)
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R     at com.gf.btv.RTDLTSS.helper.LTSSClientThread.run(LTSSClientThread.java:147)
[2/10/17 14:23:49:737 EST] 0000011e SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Comment: Are you sure they are sending in Big Endian? Some C programs assume little endian,

Comment: *What actually happens* when you try to run the client?

Comment: What protocol is the server using for the reply? Is it documented at the byte level? How can you possibly know whether your client is doing the right thing if you don't know what the server is expecting it to do? (Do you have protocol documentation? Or do you need to reverse engineer the protocol? If you have protocol documentation, share it. If you need to reverse engineer the protocol, show us the bytes the server sent you so we can try to help you do that.)

Comment: (The RST is occurring because you are not following the protocol the server is expecting you to follow, reading less data than it is sending.)

Comment: To answer Peter's question, that was one of my first concerns but the developer of the server said the endianess should be correct. Further more, we have the opposite way communication. I have a Java server and he has a C client running the same protocol and this works wonderfully. I'm able to read and parse his request and I can send my reply which he gets. I'm assuming if there was some incompatibility in the protocol the other way communication would have similar problems with the connection being reset at some point with my Java app trying to read the incoming stream from the C app.

Comment: When I run the client it sends the request to the C server, the C server receives it succesfully, does it's processing and returns a reply. Then when my client receives the response I get the error I added to the original body. The packet is RST and dropped and the connection is reset.

Comment: That's a strong indication that not even the request is being sent correctly. Time to stop guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The RST doesn't have anything to do with the PSH or the buffered reader, but if you need to read binary the reader isn't appropriate. The RST indicates that the peer closed the connection before you read from it, which is a strong indication that you're using the wrong protocol. It isn't credible that the request protocol is line-based but the response protocol is length-word-prefix-based. One or the other, or something else.

If you determine that it really is a length-word-prefix protocol, try this:

```
int messageLength = in.readShort();
byte messageBytes = new byte[messageLength];
in.readFully(messageBytes);
// etc.
```

But you need confirmation of the actual protocol. Guesswork won't get you there.

Comment: I'll ask again to make sure we are aware of the endianess, but I really don't think the problem is with this.

Comment: You should ask again to be sure you're aware of the *protocol.* You're already using two here, and it highly unlikely that both are correct. Quite possible that *neither* is correct.

Comment: I note that the supposed 'short' (2-byte int) value is 12336, which is the value for two bytes each containing the ASCII character '0'. I suspect the server is actually sending either the length or some other value in character form.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to work through this one. It seems dave_thomson was on to something. So the endianess is big endian (and just for kicks I tried changing the endianess on the receiving end without success), and as far as the message structure of the exchange, yes, the protocol is length-word-prefix-based. With the length of the stream at the beginning of it.

I did the cast from byte to int and this didn't cause the connection to be reset, so it got a little further, now I'm dealing with java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, working through that one now.